# Best way to select various elements - styled components

Tags: cypress

I have a checkbox that has nested elements. Whats the easiest way for cypress to cy.get the below? Do I need to add a tag to each elelemt?

`:nth-child(3) > :nth-child(1) > .Label--1l6kevm > .CheckboxWrapper--pil68f > .StyledCheckbox--a0y8w7`

Comment: Can you provide a sample HTML? That will be easier to determine what an effective CSS selector would be than the string you've provided.